# Footer doesn't stay down in mobile view

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

So I'm just playing around with CSS and used "vh" to give heights to elements so that i could make them bigger and use scroll animations. However when i used this my footer in the mobile view doesn't stay down no matter what css trick I use

I've already tried the following links to solve my problem,

[how to keep your footer where it belongs](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/)

[footer not sitting at bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378267/footer-not-sitting-at-bottom-of-the-page)

[keep that damn footer at the bottom](https://medium.com/@zerox/keep-that-damn-footer-at-the-bottom-c7a921cb9551)

The third URL kind of worked but I couldn't scroll past a bit of the content.

```css
html,body {
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background: #ec9b3b;
 color: #fff;
}

.slide-right {
 -webkit-animation: slide-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
 animation: slide-in-left 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}
.fade-in-bottom {
 -webkit-animation: fade-in-bottom 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) 0.3s both;
 animation: fade-in-bottom 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.390, 0.575, 0.565, 1.000) 0.3s both;
}
.banner-text {
 color: #fff;
 padding-top: 8%;
 padding-left: 8%;
 padding-right: 8%;
}
.navbar {
 min-height: 14vh;
}

.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0 15px;
 height: 14vh;
 line-height: 14vh;
}

.navbar-toggle {
 /* (80px - button height 34px) / 2 = 23px */
 margin-top: 23px;
 padding: 9px 10px !important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-nav > li > a {
  /* (80px - line-height of 27px) / 2 = 26.5px */
  padding-top: 26.5px;
  padding-bottom: 26.5px;
  line-height: 27px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <!-- Bootstrap CSS Requirement -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"
 >
 <!-- AOS CSS Library -->
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Animate.css file for animations -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css">
 <!-- Google Fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600|Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <title>SiddhantNair</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div style="padding: 20px;">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">NairSiddhant.dev</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
     
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
       </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
 </div>

 <div style="height: 80vh;">
  <h1 class="slide-right banner-text">Welcome to my Website,</h1>
  <h1 class="slide-right" style="padding-left: 8%; padding-right: 8%;">You can learn more about my projects here!</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="container" style="padding: 32px; height: 100vh;">
  <div data-aos="zoom-in-up">
   <p class="text-justify">
    Quisque eget tristique neque. Praesent lacinia massa quis erat malesuada vulputate. 
    Curabitur rhoncus ligula est, vel ullamcorper dolor iaculis ut. Maecenas dictum ornare 
    sagittis. In maximus efficitur pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Sed quis pulvinar massa, 
    id cursus mauris. Proin eget tempor tellus.
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <footer style="background: #fff; height: 8vh;">
  <p style="color: black; margin: auto; padding: 16px; padding-left: 8%;">copyright &copy; 2019 Siddhant Nair.</p>
 </footer>

 <!-- Bootstrap JS Requirements -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 </script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
 <script>
  AOS.init();
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this example:

https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#article-header-id-3

this IMO is one of the best ways to do it. Flexbox is a nice and easy concept to get your head around.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest technique to implement Sticky footers.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#container {
  max-height: 300px;
  background: gold;
  overflow: auto;
}
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: white;
  height: 1200px;
}
#sticky {
  padding: 15px;
  background: grey;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
 <br /><br />
 <div>
   Main content
 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sticky">You could wrap your footer's content inside this div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly check this code below. I have tried it and it works to make it sticky at the bottom:

```
position:fixed;width:100%; bottom:0px;"
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I figured it out. The code does exactly what we're asking for technically, so I realised instead of specifying a fixed hieght of 100vh I should've specified it as a minimum height then the footer gets pushed to where it should be.